# How to remove/revoke access token from the LinkedIn

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn API.
I have done all process to retrieve access token.
but never show anywhere to remove/revoke access token from the LinkedIn.
Please Help.!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you store the secret in your DB simply delete it and the access will be revoked.

I believe that if you wish for the user to revoke access to your app the user must to go linkedin and do it, much like Facebook.

As confirmed here: http://developer.linkedin.com/forum/how-really-revoke-apps-oauth-access-token linkedin does not have a programmable API for what you wanna do.

But before you remove it from DB you can invalidate the token which is like an extra step to take by cURLing https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/invalidateToken with your token I believe.

#### Edit

As @Paul corrects, it is actually quite important to invalidate the tokens with LinkedIn. So doing that and then removing from DB is, as he says, the correct way.

Comment: The `GET` call to `https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/invalidateToken` is important, as it effectively sign's the user out of their current LinkedIn session - pairing that with removing the tokens from your local datastore is the right way to do it.